# Not able to understand this snippet about ES6 destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading the [latest one of You Don't Know JS series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/cc82d7c8f4872ceee87a5c3b193ee846c6ab0ecc/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#nested-defaults-destructured-and-restructured) and being completely lost when it goes to the destructuring part. Please help me to understand the snippet here please. The context here is about to put some specified configurations in effect while other defaults still available.

the defaults:

```
var defaults = {
    options: {
        remove: true,
        enable: false,
        instance: {}
    },
    log: {
        warn: true,
        error: true
    }
};
```

the config:

```
var config = {
    options: {
        remove: false,
        instance: null
    }
};
```

how does the author accomplish

```
config.options = config.options || {};
config.log = config.log || {};
({
    options: {
        remove: config.options.remove = defaults.options.remove,
        enable: config.options.enable = defaults.options.enable,
        instance: config.options.instance =
                      defaults.options.instance
    } = {},
    log: {
        warn: config.log.warn = defaults.log.warn,
        error: config.log.error = defaults.log.error
    } = {}
} = config);
```

and the author made such description about the snippet:

> The previous snippet’s approach works because I’m hacking the
>   destructuring and defaults mechanism to do the property === undefined
>   checks and assignment decisions for me. It’s a trick in that I’m
>   destructuring config (see the = config at the end of the snippet), but
>   I’m reassigning all the destructured values right back into config,
>   with the config.options.enable assignment references.

The most confused one is the last sentence: **with the config.options.enable assignment references.** What is the difference between config.options.enable and other properties of config.options?

Could you please do some explanation about the code and the descriptions for me? Thank you!

Comment: Ugh! This is what I call _cute JavaScript_, where the author does something "clever" at the expense of readability, making it difficult for future readers to reason about the code.

Comment: This would be shorter and easier to understand if the author simply did a deep merge before destructuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is using destructuring as mechanism for deep-merging objects. It's weird, don't do it.

To answer your question directly:

> What is the difference between config.options.enable and other properties of config.options?

There's no difference. The author is using `config.options.enable` to refer to ALL of the lines that look like `config.options.x = defaults.options.x`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that's not perfect, since this fails on non-`undefined` falsy values.

Comment: @loganfsmyth you're absolutely right, and the author has a better explanation in the text itself (which I've now linked from the question.) I've updated my answer to address OP's specific question.

Comment: @Mathletics Thank you! After reviewing the article, I finally got the whole picture and keep in mind that the right one to the colon `config.options.x` is the destination. Could you please kindly let me know what does `false promise` in `Not as nice as the false promise of Object.assign(..) (being that it's shallow only)` mean?

Comment: @krave if you do `Object.assign({}, defaults, config)`, since is is a _shallow_ merge, `defaults.options` will be completely overwritten by `config.options` instead of merging the values. So it's a "false promise" because it _looks_ like you'd get the right values, but in fact you do not.

Comment: @Mathletics Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

It's a typo on my part. I just filed an issue to address it in the second edition. I should have said `config.enable.XYZ` to make it clear that I'm referring to all of them, not just that one. Sorry for my mistake causing you confusion.